# How to convert an ASCII character to a number using Irvine32 in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, decimal, ascii, irvine32

We're basically supposed to use ReadChar to read an inputted number from the user, then convert it to decimal by subtracting 30h. For some reason, the output is giving be random characters instead of numbers. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
.data
    XValue BYTE "Input X = ", 0
    YValue BYTE "Input Y = ", 0
    WValue BYTE "Output W = ", 0
    A DWORD 200
    X DWORD 0
    Y DWORD 0
    W DWORD 0
    Loc1 DWORD ?
    Loc2 DWORD ?
    Loc3 DWORD ?
    sum DWORD ?

.code
 main proc
    mov ecx,  4
    mov edx, OFFSET XValue ;
    call WriteString ;
L1:
    mov eax, 10
    mul X
    mov X, eax
    call ReadChar
    sub eax, 30h
    add eax, X  
    mov X, eax
    call WriteChar
    loop L1
    call WriteChar
    mov eax, X
    call Crlf
```

Comment: Random like what?  You're using `WriteChar` inside the loop on an integer value which appears to be the running total of `total = total*10 + (digit - '0')`, although you do the multiply in a pretty inefficient way (instead of `imul edx, 10` or something) and store/reload X instead of keeping values in registers.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to output a multidigit number as a single character.

Answer (score 0):

You are using WriteChar instead of ReadChar.

Comment: Which instance of `WriteChar` do you think should be `ReadChar`?  There's already one `ReadChar` in the loop to get ASCII digits.  I think 
hs takeuch is right that the problem is using `WriteChar` at the end (and maybe inside the loop, depending on what that was supposed to be for) instead of `WriteDec`